# How to get previews object

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

For this site http://eco-tech.bhbcom.net/

On click image link I need to get ALT of previews image link and next image link.

[image: look image]

How to get previews object with same class?

My code:

```
$(this).prev('.colorbox-iframe').find('img').attr('alt');
$(this).next('.colorbox-iframe').find('img').attr('alt');
```

But in console.log I have undefined.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you are intending something like this...

```
<div>
  <img alt="x" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100" />
</div>

<div>
  <img alt="y" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100" />
</div>

<div>
  <img alt="z" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100" />
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    $('div img').each(function() {
    $(this).click(function() {
      var alt = $(this).attr('alt');
      var alt_prev = $(this).closest('div').prev('div').children('img').attr('alt');
      var alt_next = $(this).closest('div').next('div').children('img').attr('alt');

      if (alt_prev === undefined)
        alt_prev = $('div:last img').attr('alt');

      if (alt_next === undefined)
        alt_next = $('div:first img').attr('alt');

      console.log('Clicked alt: ' + alt + ' Prev alt: ' + alt_prev + ' Next alt: ' + alt_next);
    });
  });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jonathanzuniga/rp5mux4m/embedded/result/